# JavaScript AngularJS Brackets Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing:

```
myArray.push(pageCount);
```

then I have something like:

```
$scope.myArray = Pages.getAllPageCount();
```

Finally when I display with AngularJS (my .html).

```
{{myArray}}
```

If I have only value, it will display `[30]` for instance.
BUT I don't want `[` and `]` .

How can I delete it?

PS: I really need to have an Array.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `{{myArray}}`, you could use: `{{myArray.join(', ')}}`